# issue in reading XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, httpresponse

I have below XML format:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<d:query xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" m:type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchResult">
<d:ElapsedTime m:type="Edm.Int32">114</d:ElapsedTime>
<d:PrimaryQueryResult m:type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.QueryResult">
<d:CustomResults m:type="Collection(Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.CustomResult)"/>
<d:QueryId>777211db-56a9-4cb8-804d-7fd6bcd3aadd</d:QueryId>
<d:QueryRuleId m:type="Edm.Guid">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:QueryRuleId>
<d:RefinementResults m:null="true"/>
<d:RelevantResults m:type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.RelevantResults">
<d:GroupTemplateId m:null="true"/>
<d:ItemTemplateId m:null="true"/>
<d:Properties m:type="Collection(SP.KeyValue)">
<d:element>
<d:Key>GenerationId</d:Key>
<d:Value>9223372036854775806</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int64</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>indexSystem</d:Key>
<d:Value/>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>ExecutionTimeMs</d:Key>
<d:Value>109</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int32</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>QueryModification</d:Key>
<d:Value>demoDoc -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>RenderTemplateId</d:Key>
<d:Value>
~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Group_Default.js
</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>StartRecord</d:Key>
<d:Value>0</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int32</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>IsLastBlockInSubstrate</d:Key>
<d:Value>true</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>IsFirstBlockInSubstrate</d:Key>
<d:Value>false</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>IsFirstPinnedResultBlock</d:Key>
<d:Value>false</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>IsLastPinnedResultBlock</d:Key>
<d:Value>false</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>IsFirstRankedResultBlock</d:Key>
<d:Value>true</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>IsLastRankedResultBlock</d:Key>
<d:Value>true</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>GeoLocationSource</d:Key>
<d:Value>NAM</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>MixedTableOrder</d:Key>
<d:Value>0</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int32</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
</d:Properties>
<d:ResultTitle m:null="true"/>
<d:ResultTitleUrl m:null="true"/>
<d:RowCount m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:RowCount>
<d:Table m:type="SP.SimpleDataTable">
<d:Rows>
<d:element m:type="SP.SimpleDataRow">
<d:Cells>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>Rank</d:Key>
<d:Value>28.7494258880615</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Double</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>DocId</d:Key>
<d:Value>17625071135127</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int64</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>WorkId</d:Key>
<d:Value>17625071135127</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int64</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>Title</d:Key>
<d:Value>DemoDoc</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>Author</d:Key>
<d:Value>John</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>Size</d:Key>
<d:Value>16820</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int64</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>Path</d:Key>
<d:Value>
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/MOCTeams/Dev/DemocompanyApps/DemoDoc.docx
</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>Description</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>Write</d:Key>
<d:Value>2012-08-07T16:44:00.0000000Z</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.DateTime</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>LastModifiedTime</d:Key>
<d:Value>2012-08-07T16:44:00.0000000Z</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.DateTime</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>CollapsingStatus</d:Key>
<d:Value>0</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int64</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>HitHighlightedSummary</d:Key>
<d:Value/>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>HitHighlightedProperties</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>contentclass</d:Key>
<d:Value>STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>PictureThumbnailURL</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>ServerRedirectedURL</d:Key>
<d:Value>
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/MOCTeams/Dev/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BD6D61B34-73D2-4B46-B34C-9CA1D7681545%7D&file=DemoDoc.docx&action=default&mobileredirect=true&DefaultItemOpen=1
</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>ServerRedirectedEmbedURL</d:Key>
<d:Value>
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/MOCTeams/Dev/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc={d6d61b34-73d2-4b46-b34c-9ca1d7681545}&action=interactivepreview
</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>ServerRedirectedPreviewURL</d:Key>
<d:Value>
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/MOCTeams/Dev/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc={d6d61b34-73d2-4b46-b34c-9ca1d7681545}&action=imagepreview
</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>FileExtension</d:Key>
<d:Value>docx</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>ContentTypeId</d:Key>
<d:Value>0x0101002EF4BA7F2C07354788AC1CDBF96B8C6E</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>ParentLink</d:Key>
<d:Value>
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/MOCTeams/Dev/DemocompanyApps/Forms/AllItems.aspx
</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>ViewsLifeTime</d:Key>
<d:Value>4</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int64</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>ViewsRecent</d:Key>
<d:Value>4</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int64</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>SectionNames</d:Key>
<d:Value/>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>SectionIndexes</d:Key>
<d:Value/>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>SiteLogo</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>SiteDescription</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>deeplinks</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>importance</d:Key>
<d:Value>0</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int64</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>SiteName</d:Key>
<d:Value>https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/mocteams</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>IsDocument</d:Key>
<d:Value>true</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>FileType</d:Key>
<d:Value>docx</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>IsContainer</d:Key>
<d:Value>false</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>WebTemplate</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>SecondaryFileExtension</d:Key>
<d:Value>docx</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>docaclmeta</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>SPWebUrl</d:Key>
<d:Value>
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/MOCTeams/Dev
</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>UniqueId</d:Key>
<d:Value>{D6D61B34-73D2-4B46-B34C-9CA1D7681545}</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>ProgId</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>LinkingUrl</d:Key>
<d:Value>
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/MOCTeams/Dev/DemocompanyApps/DemoDoc.docx?d=wd6d61b3473d24b46b34c9ca1d7681545
</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>SiteId</d:Key>
<d:Value>b1a40cd6-9335-4284-8b41-7d26574a8f56</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>WebId</d:Key>
<d:Value>e6213bf7-6f48-4e79-90d5-ccfee7bbdf08</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>OriginalPath</d:Key>
<d:Value>
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/MOCTeams/Dev/DemocompanyApps/DemoDoc.docx
</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>ResultTypeIdList</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>ResultTypeId</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>RenderTemplateId</d:Key>
<d:Value>
~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Default.js
</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>PartitionId</d:Key>
<d:Value>1ab41d5a-8833-4af0-82be-e3c54d03997b</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Guid</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>UrlZone</d:Key>
<d:Value>0</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int32</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>Culture</d:Key>
<d:Value>en-US</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
</d:Cells>
</d:element>
</d:Rows>
</d:Table>
<d:TotalRows m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:TotalRows>
<d:TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates>
</d:RelevantResults>
<d:SpecialTermResults m:null="true"/>
</d:PrimaryQueryResult>
<d:Properties m:type="Collection(SP.KeyValue)">
<d:element>
<d:Key>RowLimit</d:Key>
<d:Value>10</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Int32</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>SourceId</d:Key>
<d:Value>8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Guid</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>CorrelationId</d:Key>
<d:Value>c8622b9f-40b3-9000-8539-ae6db2299a08</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Guid</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>WasGroupRestricted</d:Key>
<d:Value>false</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>WordBreakerLanguage</d:Key>
<d:Value>en</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>IsPartialUpnDocIdMapping</d:Key>
<d:Value>false</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>EnableInterleaving</d:Key>
<d:Value>true</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>IsMissingUnifiedGroups</d:Key>
<d:Value>false</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>Constellation</d:Key>
<d:Value>i29EA6</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>MultiGeoSearchStatus</d:Key>
<d:Value>Full</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>IsPartial</d:Key>
<d:Value>false</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.Boolean</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>InternalRequestId</d:Key>
<d:Value>a10cf383-be13-4f36-8bf2-927fad3f759f</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element>
<d:Key>SerializedQuery</d:Key>
<d:Value>
<Query Culture="en-US" EnableStemming="True" EnablePhonetic="False" EnableNicknames="False" IgnoreAllNoiseQuery="True" SummaryLength="180" MaxSnippetLength="180" DesiredSnippetLength="90" KeywordInclusion="0" QueryText="demoDoc" QueryTemplate="" TrimDuplicates="True" Site="321cf1a7-64e8-42b4-bcb0-979df1f325ba" Web="906b0097-58fe-40f6-9d28-97bfdbff7e22" KeywordType="True" HiddenConstraints="" />
</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
</d:Properties>
<d:SecondaryQueryResults m:type="Collection(Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.QueryResult)"/>
<d:SpellingSuggestion/>
<d:TriggeredRules m:type="Collection(Edm.Guid)"/>
</d:query>
```

Currently ,i am reading it using below code:

```
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(response);

            // cycle through each child node 
            foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                // first node is the url ... have to go to nexted loc node 
                foreach (XmlNode locNode in node)
                {
                    // thereare a couple child nodes here so only take data from node named loc 
                    if (locNode.Name == "Path")
                    {
                        // get the content of the loc node 
                        string loc = locNode.InnerText;

                        // write it to the console so you can see its working 
                        Console.WriteLine(loc + Environment.NewLine);

                        // write it to the file 

                    }
                }
            }
```

Where i am getting the xml data in the response variable ( which is fetched earlier using Http request).
But,i am not getting any data  in the xDoc and code flow is coming out from   `xDoc.Load(response);`point.

Example use case : fetch value of `DocId`  from XML.

Please help,as i am new to C#.

Comment: code flow is coming out from xDoc.Load(response); - are you getting any exception here ?

Comment: Looks like your code does not anything in common with the xml structure you are trying to read. There is no element "Path" in the source xml at all. Also, you probably need to specify xml namespace "d", because the name would not match without it.

Comment: It is invalid XML you are trying to parse. "System.Xml.XmlException: ''d' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1, position 2.'". The issue is not C#, but you can't parse invalid XML. Then you have to create your own Custom XML Parser, which will be a larger task.

Comment: Try checking https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: @Kiksen i have just sent the part of xml,  ok i have updated now.

Comment: Can't you use CSOM to execute sharepoint search query ? It's easier to use in my sense

Comment: There is no URL for the namespace d: in the posted xml.  You should have an attribute in the xml starting with "xmlns:d:="URL"

Comment: @SteveB Yes, i did some online research and looks like CSOm will be fine. Can you   help me providing any link or any refrence.

Comment: @AllTech: try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/using-the-sharepoint-search-query-apis, this should be a good starting point

Comment: @jdweng i have updated the xml in the main post now,please check.

Comment: @SteveB Thank You. I have gone through the link, but i have not used SPSite in my code to fetch the result . I am simply executing HttpWebRequest and now xml file is in response. Can you guide me in that perspective.

Comment: The encoding is bad.  You have ampersands in he file which are giving errors.  The URL for some of the http links are the issues.  How are you reading the request/response?

Comment: I replaced the the & with &amp; to get rid of the errors.  The were 8 occurrences.

Comment: @AllTech, first add the correct [nuget packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.SharePoint*.CSOM+from%3AOfficeDeveloperPlatformTeam), then follow the sample in `Query using the .NET client object model` sample of the above link.

Comment: @SteveB  I amusing the code given in that link . I amusing the api https://company.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='docName" . In the results - ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery); -  i am just getting : {Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.ResultTableCollection>}

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with XML schema should be defined.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<d:Table xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" m:type="SP.SimpleDataTable">
  <d:Rows>
    <d:element m:type="SP.SimpleDataRow">
      <d:Cells>
        <d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
          <d:Key>Rank</d:Key>
          <d:Value>28.7494258880615</d:Value>
          <d:ValueType>Edm.Double</d:ValueType>
        </d:element>
        <d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
          <d:Key>DocId</d:Key>
          <d:Value>17625071135127</d:Value>
          <d:ValueType>Edm.Int64</d:ValueType>
        </d:element>

      </d:Cells>
    </d:element>
  </d:Rows>
</d:Table>
```

**CS code**

```
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
            //xDoc.Load(response);

            // cycle through each child node 
            foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                // first node is the url ... have to go to nexted loc node 
                foreach (XmlNode locNode in node)
                {
                    // thereare a couple child nodes here so only take data from node named loc 
                    var nodeList = locNode.ChildNodes;
                    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var childNodes = nodeList[i].ChildNodes;
                        for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.Count; j++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"DocId: "+childNodes[j].ChildNodes[1].InnerText + Environment.NewLine);
                            //childNodes[j].ChildNodes.AsQueryable()
                            //childNodes[i]
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Can i use response string which contains xml instead of XMLFile1.xml . Because i am getting the xml data in response string.                                        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
                    string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

Comment: Currently ,it's not working and code flow is not reaching that point , tried multiple times .

Comment: what exception do you get?

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.Xml.dll

Comment: maybe there would be an issue with yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205956/discussion-between-arvind-maurya-and-alltech).

Comment: Now the flow is going inside foreach loop ,but how to capture values like Author from xml . i.e  <d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>Title</d:Key>
<d:Value>DemoDoc</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>Author</d:Key>
<d:Value>John</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>

Comment: Can you paste the sample XML that you get as a response for API call?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account the namespaces specified at the root node.

```
        XmlDocument myXml= new XmlDocument();
        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(myXml.NameTable);

        myXml.Load(xmlPath);

        // ================Namespaces======================
        ns.AddNamespace("a", "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/");
        ns.AddNamespace("b", "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/");
        // ================================================
```

Then when you try to pull data from a node,

```
foreach (XmlNode node in myXml.SelectNodes($"//a:Table/a:Rows", ns))
                { //Do stuff}
```

Please let me know if you need a deeper explanation.

Comment: XmlDocument myXml = new XmlDocument();
                    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(myXml.NameTable);

                    myXml.Load(@"D:\Sample.xml");

                    // ================Namespaces======================
                    ns.AddNamespace("a", "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/");
                    ns.AddNamespace("b", "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/");

                    foreach (XmlNode node in myXml.SelectNodes($"//d:Table/d:Rows", ns))
                    {   
                    }  I am getting exception  at for loop.